# Object's edit mode to another object's edit mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, blender-internal-render-engine, edit-mode

Is it possible to take a part of mesh from an object in edit mode and copy paste it into another object's edit mode.

I am making a model and gloves are a separate object. I want to somehow make it and arms as single mesh what are the possible ways.